# How to edit and search data (words) in jTable?

Tags: java, user-interface, search, jtable, edit

I am beginner in Java, only know basic stuff.

I would like to know how to edit and search data inserted to `jTable`? So like I type some data in textbox and added to `jTable` and then type in a search text box to find a specific word in `jTable` so it'll show up in `jLabel`.

Then for editing, i don't even know how to do it. No idea. Plus, this all should be in a separate java class, not in .form (design) part in GUI. A sample GUI Java application would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for the basics of using tables. There are sections on:

1. `Concepts: Editor and Renderers`
2. `Sorting and Filtering`. You might want to use filtering to search for a string.